# How do I insert a record in SQL with reserved word "from"?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I've noticed that one of our fields is named "from" because the table is for saving emails. So someone used "from" which is a reserved word from database.

I've used

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO email_setting (client_id, [from], created_by) VALUES (9251 , 'mjmsample@gmail.com', 1)")
```

I've also tried these codes

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO email_setting e (e.client_id, e.from, e.created_by) VALUES (9251 , 'mjmsample@gmail.com', 1)")

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO email_setting ('client_id', 'from', 'created_by') VALUES (9251 , 'mjmsample@gmail.com', 1)")
```

All of these but no luck, is there any workaround this?

Comment: Use backticks `\`` - `\`from\``

Comment: Using backticks permits you to use reserved text and space characters.

Comment: No. Change the column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why people never use backticks!

```
INSERT INTO `email_setting` `e` (`e`.`client_id`, `e`.`from`, `e`.`created_by`)
```

Comment: @fvu Which one buddy?

Comment: the `"` one, which is standard (` is MySQL specific)

Comment: @fvu Ah yeah... But this is for MySQL. So backticks are the best. `:)`

Comment: how to solve when insertion is done through spark dataframe having reserved keyword in dataframe ??

Comment: @potterpod What's spark dataframe? Oh, this is PHP & MySQL. Not Java & SparkQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Use `` backtick symbol to use reserved keyword in mysql.It is a good practice to add backtick to all fields. 

USE `from` with backtick instead of 'from' with single quotes.

 $this->db->query("INSERT INTO email_setting (`client_id`, `from`, `created_by`) VALUES (9251 , 'mjmsample@gmail.com', 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backtick(`) quotes instead of '

Answer (score 0):

You need to use back ticks for MySQL reserved keywords:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `email_setting` (`client_id`, `from`, `created_by`) VALUES (9251 , 'mjmsample@gmail.com', 1)")
```

It's a good habit to use back ticks for all MySQL-related names such as table names and columns.